# VPN connect with PowerShell not work in windows-service

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-services

I create PowerShell script from VPN connect (this work from powershell):

```
$vpnName = "VPN_NAME";
$vpn = Get-VpnConnection -Name $vpnName;
if($vpn.ConnectionStatus -eq "Disconnected"){
    rasdial $vpnName;
}
```

Next step: I create Service via http://nssm.cc. This is service worked but not connect VPN.

And next step: i convert script "ps1" via "ps2exe.ps1" to "exe". And all the same. Service work but not connect VPN.

How can I fix this? Thank.

Comment: Which user account does the service use? If Local System, try your own - or vice versa.

Comment: @vonPryz Thank you! Earned after specifying my account. I think it is necessary to put a tick "allow other users to use vpn" and then, on ideas, will work in the standard way.